# Create DIV with onMouseOver effect with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onmouseover

I would like to create a DIV element via **Javascript**, but it should have a `onMouseOver` effect.

so I know what the tags look like in HTML:

```
<div onMouseOver="doSth()" onMouseOut="doSthElse()"> </div>
```

and I know how to create my DIV:

```
var myDiv= document.createElement("div");
//style settings
document.body.appendChild(myDiv);
```

but how do I create the effect in Javascript code?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Without jQuery, this is what you want:

```
var myDiv = document.createElement('div');

myDiv.onmouseout  = doSth;
myDiv.onmouseover = doSthElse;
// with doSth & doSthElse being functions you defined somewhere else already
// otherwise you can assign a function here:
// myDiv.onmouseout = function(){};

document.body.appendChild( myDiv );
```

Comment: shame on me for not finding out by myself^^ thanks for the quick answer

Answer (score 4):

Use pure Javascript [EventTarget.addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener)

```
var myDiv= document.createElement("div");
myDiv.addEventListener("mouseover", mouseOver, false);
myDiv.addEventListener("mouseout", mouseOut, false);
document.body.appendChild(myDiv);
function mouseOver()
{  
   //do something
}

function mouseOut()
{  
   //do something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use jQuery [`.hover()`:](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

```
$('#myDiv').hover(doSth, doSthElse);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to display some other element or change the style of the div, you can also use a CSS class:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.className = "hoverEffect";
```

Then you can style the the div using the CSS :hover selector. For example:

```
div.hoverEffect:hover {
    color:#fff;
}

div.hoverEffect child {
    display:none;
}

div.hoverEffect:hover child {
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use `.attr()` jquery:

```
$(myDiv).attr("onMouseOver","doSth()");
$(myDiv).attr("onMouseOut","doSthElse()");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass all calls function on attributes looks like this:

```
$('#idColor').attr("onMouseOver","showStone('"+arr[i]+"')");
```

For example:

```
var arr = new Array();
arr.push("granite-alaskawhite.jpg");
arr.push("granite-bordeauxriver.jpg");
arr.push("granite-copenhagen.jpg");

for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {      
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    var idColor = 'color' + i;
    img.id = idColor;
    img.src = "assets/images/projects3d/colors/" + arr[i];
    img.className = 'proj-items';

    $("#colors").append(img);

    //Call functions
    $('#' + idColor).attr("onMouseOut","hideStone()");
    $('#' + idColor).attr("onMouseOver","showStone('"+arr[i]+"')");

}


function hideStone() {
    $("#p3ddesc").html( "" );
    $('#p3ddesc').attr("class","p3ddesc");
}

function showStone( stoneTxt ) {
    $("#p3ddesc").html( stoneTxt );
    $('#p3ddesc').attr("class","p3ddesc-active");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One option without using JQuery, is `setAttribute()`. Unlike some other options, it also allows you to set a parameter in your function call. For example, passing the parameter `this` in the case that your function needs to alter the calling element.

```js
var myDiv= document.createElement("div");
myDiv.setAttribute("onmouseover", "myFunction(this)")
document.body.appendChild(myDiv);
```